# XML Content Management System

Tags: php, xml, content-management-system

Just a quick question I know how I would build a cms using a database but why would you want to create a cms with xml?

What are the pros and con's using xml also if I was to build a cms with xml would I need the help of a database of does xml just remove the need of a database?

Answer (score 1):

I havent't seen CMS without a database in a while.

I think most of those were developed because "a long time ago" you didn't always get access to a database when purchasing/renting webspace.

Comment: Ahh yeah I see, So xml is the older version cms ?

Comment: it's not the "older version" it's just another approach on storing data

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in storing your data in a changing format. XML definitely allows that - being able to define your own tags at will is somewhat akin to being able to add and remove columns without migrating data.

XML can remove the usage of a database - but as the size of the XML file grows, lookup and search become ever more costly. For a personal content management system - especially one where you are looking at the beginning of a file in your most common use case - it could be an acceptable solution.

Making a CMS like this would be something like using [TiddlyWiki](http://www.tiddlywiki.com), which is a single html file that hosts an entire wiki.

For even slightly larger scale CMS, I would immediately opt for a database - probably SQLite for smaller scale, because it's the thing to do nowadays.

Comment: So for small scale cms xml is fine ? What kind of editors can edit xml files ? 

A client at work has asked for an xml cms but I still think a db version would be better

Comment: Define 'small scale.' I would say for a few users generating less than 10MB of data, you might be able to get away with XML. I would definitely recommend a db version as well. 

You can edit XML with something as simple as Notepad, though I might recommend something with syntax highlighting like Notepad2.

If you're still thinking of doing an XML CMS, or the client demands it, write up a quick prototype and generate a decent amount of data - just to see what sort of performance problems you might run into up-front, and present those to the customer to see if they're acceptable.